# How to resize ribbon hight to image dinamicly by CSS?

Tags: css, resize

I am designing a Sharepoint 2016 page. I added a picture to the top ribbon and resized the pisture's width to the monitor size. My problem is that the height of the picture is too long so the top of the picture is not displayed. So I would like to resize the ribbon's height to the hight of the picture. The current code is:

```
div#s4-titlerow.ms-dialogHidden{
background-image: url("url.png");
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

So the goal is to not cut the head of the people and they also have legs! so I wanna display the full image:

[image]

Original:

[image]

Also I am not sure about the grey row is on top of my image or my image's hight is too short. I am not a CSS/HTML programmer so pls lend me a hand.

Comment: instead of cover use `100% auto` and make the position right

Comment: I tryed to change to "background-size: 100% auto;" and "background-position: right;" but still the same.

Comment: can you share the link of the image ?

Comment: I added the original to the post.

Comment: Do u have more tips? I tryed all combinition of 100% and auto at background-size , but none of them was good.